# Разделение ArrayList<T>something по элементам, которые повторяются и записать в ArrayList<ArrayList<T>>separated

Tags: java, arraylist, split

```
package test;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {

    static ArrayList<List> full = new ArrayList<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<String> alfaBet = new ArrayList<>();
        String split = "Split";
        /*
    добавляем в alfaBet заглавные буквы и разделяем словом. Возможны любые данные, начинаются с разделителя
    но нужно разделить по определенному критерию, который повторяеся неопределенное количество раз,
    этот for для примера, повторение может быть и через любое, разное количесто элементов
         */
        for (int i = 65; i <= 90; i++) {
            if (i % 5 == 0) {
                alfaBet.add(split);
            }
            alfaBet.add(Character.toString((char) i));
        }
        splitArray(alfaBet, split);
        full.forEach(System.out::println);
    }
// метод который разделяет ArrayList, но только до первого split.
//пытался в циклы засунуть выдает ConcurrentModificationException

    public static void splitArray(ArrayList<String> arr, String split) {
        List<String> medium = new ArrayList<>(arr);
        List<String> additional = new ArrayList<>();
        medium.remove(0);
        medium.add(split);
        if (medium.contains(split)) {
            for (String m : medium) {
                if (!m.equals(split)) {
                    additional.add(m);
                } else {
                    break;
                }
            }
            full.add(additional);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

К исключению приводит некорректное удаление из коллекции. Удаление - вообще нежелательная операция, лучше обходиться без нее, тем более в вашем случае это вообще не проблема:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        ArrayList<String> alfaBet = new ArrayList<>();
        String split = "Split";
        
        for (int i = 65; i <= 90; i++) {
            if (i % 5 == 0) {
                alfaBet.add(split);
            }
            alfaBet.add(Character.toString((char) i));
        }
        
        System.out.println(alfaBet);                
        List<List<String>> result = splitArray(alfaBet, split);
        System.out.println(result);
        
    }
    
    private static List<List<String>> splitArray(ArrayList<String> source, String split) {
        
        List<List<String>> result = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> additional = new ArrayList<>();
        
        for (String value : source) {
            if (split.equals(value)) {
                if (additional.isEmpty()) continue;
                result.add(additional);
                additional = new ArrayList<>();
            }
            else additional.add(value);
        }
        if (!additional.isEmpty())result.add(additional);
        return result;
    }

}
```

Comment: Дмитрий, спасибо за подсказку! Но увы не совсем корректно работает, не добавляет Элементы после последнего split, в нашем случае Z теряется, В любом случае Спасибо, дали направление для размышления. Для начинающих изучать Это сильная подмога!

Comment: @TankmanBuba  не за что, рад ,что помогло, только не понял, над чем вы еще потом сидели? решение, которое я вам дал, написано за 2 минуты. там просто не хватает одной строчки кода перед инструкцией  возврата : if (!additional.isEmpty())result.add(additional); это решается за 10 секунд. ответ, разумеется, исправил)

Comment: начал изучать недавно.  поэтому сидел

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо Дмитрию за подсказку, посидел и написал следующее, задачу вроде бы решает, но похоже на подгонку под результат, начал изучать недавно, поэтому не знаю насколько это правильно.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<String> alfaBet = new ArrayList<>();
        String split = "Split";
        /*
        добавляем в alfaBet заглавные буквы и разделяем словом. Возможны любые данные, начинаются с разделителя
        но нужно разделить по определенному критерию, который повторяеся неопределенное количество раз,
        этот for для примера, повторение может быть и через любое, разное количесто элементов
        */
        for (int i = 65; i <= 90; i++) {
            if (i % 5 == 0) alfaBet.add(split);
            alfaBet.add(Character.toString((char) i));
        }
        alfaBet.forEach(System.out::println);
        List<List<String>> result = splitArray(alfaBet, split);
        for (List<String> list : result) {
            list.forEach(System.out::println);
            System.out.println();
        }

    }
    public static List<List<String>> splitArray (ArrayList<String> source, String split) {
        List<List<String>> result = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> additional = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 1; i < source.size(); i++) {
            if (source.get(i).equals(split)) {
                result.add(additional);
                additional = new ArrayList<>();
            } else {
                additional.add(source.get(i));
                if (i == source.size()-1)
                    result.add(additional);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```